# ListIterator last hasNext() something not understood

Tags: java, iterator, listiterator

Let's say I run this code, it shows me this : 1 10 2 10 3 10

```
public class Test1{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
    list.add((1));
    list.add((2));
    list.add((3));
    ListIterator<Integer> it = list.listIterator();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        it.next();
        it.add((10));
    }
    for(Integer i : list){
        System.out.println(i);
    }        
}
```

What I don't get is why the last `hasNext()` takes place even thought we should be at the end of the *list* (in my understanding). On the element 3.

First, iterator is on 1. `hasNext()` return `true` because *list* has 2 after.
So i go into the loop, `it.next()` returns me 1 and set the cursor on 2. When I add 10 it takes place in the *cursor* place so between 1 and 2.
then, `it.next()` returns me 2 and set the cursor to 3. Then I add 10 between 2 and 3.
But at this point, I don't have the next of 3, so why do `hasNext()` return true, to add 12 at the last place of the list?

Answer (score 3):

Iterators in Java are created to point to the place **before the start of the list**, so the first call to `next()` returns the first element, if the list has one. Thus, you will go over all the items of the list, and add `10` after each one.

Answer (score 2):

The cursor is always *between* elements. When you add an element via the list iterator, the item is added at the cursor's position and the cursor is moved to after the item you just inserted. This is also explained [in the javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html).

Think of the cursor position that way, in order:

```
    1      2       3
  ^
hasNext? yes => call next (returns 1)
    1      2       3
        ^
call add
    1      10      2       3
               ^
hasNext? yes => call next (returns 2)
    1      10      2       3
                       ^
call add
    1      10      2       10         3
                                ^
hasNext? yes => call next (returns 3)
    1      10      2       10         3
                                           ^
call add
    1      10      2       10         3       10
                                                       ^
hasNext? no => exit loop
```